# Determine Whether the Function is even, odd, or neither $g(x) = 1-x^4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

These questions give me a problem since the rules of distribution seem not to apply to them, for example:

Determine whether the following function is even, odd, or neither?
$g(x)= 1-x^4 $

$g(-x) =1 - (-1x)^4$

$1-(+1x^4)$

distribute the negative
$1-1x^4$

factor out the negative

$-1 (-1 +1x^4)$

Thus this function is neither, however, the book says it is even, why?

Why are the rules of distribution of the negative sign not being applied here?

Comment: You found, correctly, that $g(-x)=1-x^4$.  You need to notice that this equals $g(x)$, so the function is even.

Comment: why did you factor out the $-1$ in the last step?

Comment: because that is one of the steps, isn't it? Or am I supposed to stop at some point?

Comment: I guess I do not need to factor out the negative after I have place it in the function and it resembles the original function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of even function is $\forall x$ $$f(x)=f(-x)$$
The definition of odd function is $$f(x)=-f(-x)$$
The function is neither iff
$$f(x)\not=\pm f(-x)$$
From those definitions can you conclude why the function is even?

Comment: How about h(x) 2x-x^6 = -2x-+x, if I factor out the -1 I get -(2x--x), thus -(2x?x) which means neither. I am just confused about factoring? When I factor out negatives do I factor from the factors or the operators, example, (a-b) = -1(-a--b)

Comment: Why do you factor (-1)?It doesn't help you at all.Anyway if you factor $(-1)$ than you just change signs $(+a-b)=(-1)(-a+b)$

Answer (score 4):

Recall that $(-x)^2 = (-x)(-x)  = x^2\geq 0 \forall x$. And note that $(-x)^4 = ((-x)^2)^2 = (x^2)^2 = x^4$.

Indeed, $(-x)^{2n} = x^{2n}$ when $n \in \mathbb Z$.

$$g(-x) = (1-(-x)^4) = 1 - x^4 = g(x) $$

which is what you found after "distributing the negative": $1 - 1\cdot x^4 = 1- x^4$.

So, what does it mean when $g(x) = g(-x)?$

Comment: You mean $g(-x)$

Comment: You are raising the negative 1 to the forth power also. The way one is supposed to solve these problems seem very arbitrary. I am following PEMDAS. How come it does not apply here?

Comment: $(-1)^4 = (-1)(-1)(-1)(-1)= ----(1) = 1$